# In quicksight, how to apply a filter on a specific value?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have this case, bar chart visual that shows the volume of events (A, B, C). For Event A only I want to apply a specific filter    'Customer Type> New'  and for the rest I do not want to apply the filter. So the end result will be, in the same visual:

'''
Volume of A (Customer type: New)
Volume of B (Customer type: New and Old)
Volume of C (Customer type: New and Old)
'''

is this possible in Quicksight? if so , what are the possible solutions?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can apply filters to visuals, but the filters are applied uniformly across the visuals. This means that if you apply a filter to a visual, it will be applied to all the data points in that visual. Unfortunately, QS does not support applying different filters to different parts of the same visual.

There may be some workarounds to consider:

- **Create separate visuals for each event**: You can create separate bar charts for each event (A, B, C). For Event A, you can apply the 'Customer Type > New' filter. For Events B and C, you can create the bar charts without any filter. This way, you can have the desired result in separate visuals;
- **Use calculated fields**: You can create a calculated field that represents the volume of each event with the applied filter. For example, for Event A, you can create a calculated field that only includes 'Customer Type > New'. For Events B and C, you can create calculated fields that include both 'Customer Type > New' and 'Customer Type > Old'. Then, you can use these calculated fields in your bar chart. Note that this approach requires some knowledge of SQL or a similar language, as you will need to write the formula for the calculated field.